# Footsteps for Kontakt

Tags: foley, footsteps, post-production, sound-libraries

Try this free footsteps patch. Give me feedback please.
Requires the full retail version of Native Instruments Kontakt 4.2.3 or later.

http://www.signoaudiodesign.com

Thanks

Comment: downloading now! thx

Comment: This beats sampling Fred Astaire's tap dancing. Cheers.

Comment: Hi arX,

Good idea... tap dance patch for Kontakt!! ;O)
Thanks for your comment
Bernard

Comment: Hey! Thanks - I will check this out. Great idea!

Comment: Thanks sampleism - I will upload a new version of the patch soon.

Comment: Hi, There's an upgrade to the footsteps patch for Kontakt.
There's also a NEW FREE instrument call Fresh snow footsteps. Try it [here](http://www.signoaudiodesign.com), it's free. Cheers